# Linux: Find total filesize of files path inside a file

Tags: linux

I have a file containing some file paths like:

```
./file1
./dir/file2
./dir3/dir4/fil3
etc
```

How can i find the total filesize of all of them? I know about "du" for getting the filesize of single file but no idea how to use a file.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use du to give total size of multiple files

```
 cat file | tr "\n" "\0" | du -ch --files0-from=- | tail -n1
```

Use awk for getting file size

```
 cat file | awk  '{system("ls -l " $0)}' | awk '{ TOTAL += $5} END { print TOTAL}'
```

Comment: that is returning the filesize of the file

Comment: Its working but my file is very big and i am getting: -bash: /usr/bin/du: Argument list too long

Comment: Try using 'tr "\n" "\0" <file-list | du --files0-from=-' as given below then. There should be no problem even with rather long file lists.

Comment: As mikyra suggested please use tr. 
cat file | tr "\n" "\0"  | du -ch --files0-from=- | tail -n1

Comment: @keepwalking you can use awk and ls to get file size. Please see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

### GNU coreutils du only suggestion

EDIT: the named option `--files0-from` is a GNU extension, so this suggested solution won't work with any non GNU coreutils du version. As you don't semm to have it the `awk` version posted by Vivek Goel is the one you should try instead.

You already answered your own question. Using `du` is the key. The "missing" option you're looking for might be this one found in the manual pages. (man du)

> --files0-from=F
>   summarize  disk usage of the NUL-terminated file names specified in file F; If F is - then read names from standard input

Usage would be like this:

```
tr "\n" "\0" <file-list | du --files0-from=-
```

Comment: i am getting: du: illegal option -- -
usage: du [-Aclnx] [-H | -L | -P] [-h | -k | -m ] [-a | -s | -d depth] [-B blocksize] [-I mask] [-t threshold] [file ...]

Comment: oops - one thing I forgot to mention `--files0-from` is a GNU extension, so it won't work with busybox du or the like. If `du --version` doesn't report (GNU coreutils) the `--files0-from` otpion won't be present.